# Give airspace to do something

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching This Morning, the British talk show, and in the midst of it (almost 1 minute and 20 seconds into the video) the guest complaining about why people described her daughter as beautiful, judging her looks and all that while praised her boys on their physicality and intelligence. She says

> [So why would I give airspace to praise her for something that has nothing to do with her...](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zVdQBxlZfak)

Based on the context I can figure out she means *letting people do that*, but I fail to find it in a reliable source. Is it a common expression or an improvisation?

Comment: It seems an improvisation on **air-time**.  Time "on the air".  **airspace** is the region of sky above a geographic area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not heard "airspace" being used like that before.  It appears to be a metaphor, perhaps from the broadcasting meaning of "airspace"

> Airspace: a few neighboring frequencies available for broadcasting within a particular frequency band.

I understand it to be about what the mother chooses to do, not about *letting other people*. "There is a limited amount of 'airspace' for me to 'broadcast' things to my daughter. Why would I waste this limited time/space to praise her for something that has nothing to do with her."

Answer (score 1):

It is a mistake. I believe they meant to say "air**time**".

"Airtime" is a broadcasting term referring to time allocated for TV or radio programmes.

"Airspace" is an aeronautic term referring to the air allocated for aircraft to fly in.

In a similar gaff, I recently saw a local newspaper refer to a radio presenter as "voice of the airways", when they really meant to say "air**waves**" (another broadcasting term mainly used for radio).

The meaning of *giving airtime to* somebody is letting them speak on TV or radio. If someone has controversial views that perhaps ought not to be broadcast then a presenter or anchor may be heard to say something similar to "I'm not giving you airtime for that".

If I understand your question correctly though it wasn't one of the presenters who used this incorrect idiom, it was a guest. I can only assume that either the guest was attempting to use what they thought was a broadcasting term, or else the idiom has crossed over from broadcasting terminology and into the wider consciousness where it is being used either figuratively, or more likely out-of-context.